# $_Server['remote_addr] returns same ip for every user

Tags: php, ip

I'm trying to get the visitors ip addresses but I'm unable to do so. I tried to get the visitor ip address from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but it returns the same ip for every visitor.

I get several codes from different forums for getting the ip address of the visitor but no luck.

Following is the code I tried.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

and also the following

```
if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Can someone tell me what can be the problem? Is there could be any configuration on the server which causes this issue?

OR is there any code I should try?

Comment: All users are behind the same Proxy?

Comment: Is your server behind a load balancer/reverse proxy…? Then you'd probably always see its IP. Whether that proxy also forwards the original IP to you depends on its setup, consult its documentation.

Comment: can you determine what ip address that is? Is it a public address?